# Am I able to clean white background in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, cleaning, retouching

I have a photo of an object on almost clean white background (see below).

As you can see the bottom of the photo is perfectly clean white, but the topmost of the picture is slightly gray which is not very good.

If I'd need to work with only one photo I'd use any editor like Photoshop or GIMP to select all background and just delete it. However I have about 500 such photos so I'm looking for a faster way for clearing. Probably Lightroom has any tool to do this job?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightroom can't do any background deletion (so that this area gets transparent). If pure white is sufficient, you have the following ways to achieve this:

- Push up the whites on the whole image
- Use an adjustment-brush and push up the higlights / exposure until it gets white enough
- Use the spot removal tool and copy some white from another area

Each of these ways can be copied across all images like any other adjustment in a very fast way. Use the "sync" button and select the appropriate adjustments you want to copy.

Comment: Can you explain or point to a tutorial on how one might sync adjustment  brush or spot removal work across multiple images?